# Checking whether an Optional object isn't Empty and null

Tags: java, java-8, null, option-type, nullable

I am working on sprint boot application, and I am working on SonarQube blocker resolving an issue.

So I get one issue to be resolved:

> Ensure this "Optional" could never be null and remove this null-check.

So I have changed the condition from

```
myObj != null -> Optional.ofNullable(myObj).isPresent()
```

I can't use `myObj.isPresent()` directly as `myObj` can be `null`, so it will throw null pointers.

Now I'm stacked in one situation when `myObj` is empty as

```
myObj= Optional.empty();
Optional.ofNullable(myObj).isPresent(); // True
myObj.isPresent(); // False;
```

So as I have mentioned I have changed my condition checking `myObj!=null` with `Optional.ofNullable(myObj).isPresent()`, it will work fine for `null` object and if object is empty then it will be true for empty object and when I access `get()` on object then it'll throw : **No value present**

How can I avoid `null` and ***empty*** together in one condition?

I don't want to add && condition to check for non-empty of myObj as :

```
Optional.ofNullable(myObj).isPresent() && !myObj.isEmpty()
```

Can I check this with single statement for null as well for empty or vice-versa?

Comment: As from above Optional.ofNullable(myObj).isPresent() -> True in if and very next line if I try myObj.get() to get object then it will throw : No value present, so I don't want such condition

Comment: If you are getting an object as a **value** (that could be `null`) inside the method, you shouldn't entail `Optional` at all. It doesn't makes your code cleaner, `Optional` is meant to be used only as a **return type**.

Comment: My objects are created using Optional, so I need to use Optional to check the conditions.

Comment: You mean `myObj` is of type `Optional`?

Comment: Yes Optional<T> myObj.

Comment: SonarQube told you “*Ensure this ‘Optional’ could never be null*”, not “hide this null-check in some other construct”.

Answer (score 2):

`Optional` type, it was introduces in JDK for only one particular purpose - to be used as a ***return type*** when return well could potentially be `null`. Any other cases when *optional* is utilized just in order to chain on it, or as a type of parameter or field isn't considered to be a good practice.

You definitely shouldn't wrap the `Optional` object with another `Optional`.

The fact that you have an optional that could be `null` itself isn't a good indicator. It must not happen in the first place. Because of that you hardly can come up with a clean and elegant solution.

Accessing the value isn't the actual problem, the problem is you optional could potentially be `null`. It shouldn't be the case, you must not return `null` instead of *optional*. That's the rule of thumb.

You could use either of these, but bear in mind that it doesn't eliminate the problem, rather disguises it:

```
if (Stream.ofNullable(myObj).anyMatch(Optional::isPresent)) {
    something = myObj.get();
}
```

```
something = Stream
        .ofNullable(myObj)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .findFirst().orElse(defaultValue);
```

Your issue is stated as:

> Ensure this "Optional" could never be null and remove this null-check.

As I understand this, you have to address the root of the problem: find out from where `null` *optionals* are coming from and replace `null` with an empty *optional*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can not change existing code that is using Option<T> for each variable created. I need solution for empty and null to be check. with Optional in one.

Comment: @NeelamSharma The condition above doesn't require any changes. It'll work only if `myObj` is an optional.

Comment: @NeelamSharma In order to utilize effectively optional object, it must be either empty or contain a value. Optional isn't designed to be `null`, conversely it's meant to avoid `null` values. In the station you have, you need to use a condition that checks that object is not `null`.

Comment: `Objects.nonNull(myObj)` is just a `myObj != null` in disguise. It’s not improving anything. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)) states, the purpose of this method is to support `Object::nonNull` predicates, not to replace every null-check of an application.

Comment: @Holger My bad, I've messed the things. Amended